# Void * space in a struct instead of malloc

Tags: c, malloc, c99

I currently have a struct

```
typedef struct Entry {
    int counter;
    void *block;
} Entry;
```

and a mmap'ed block of memory

```
void *memPtr = mmap(NULL, someSize*1024, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, 
                        MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);
```

which I then add entries to the first part all the time (which is stupid, but that part's a bit irrelevant) as such:

```
int AddEntry(void *data) {
   Entry entry;
   entry.counter = 1;
   entry.block = malloc(sizeof(char *) * SECTOR_SIZE);
   memcpy(entry.block, data, SECTOR_SIZE);
   memcpy(&memPtr[0], &entry, sizeof(Entry));
   return 0;
}
```

The problem here is that `Entry` is only 16 bytes long because `block` is a `void pointer`. What's the best way to ensure that block is actually the size of sizeof(char *) * SECTOR_SIZE and actually has enough space for data, and how would one load `data` into `entry.block`?

Thanks!

Comment: *The problem here is that Entry is only 16 bytes long because block is a void pointer* I don't understand why that is a problem. What are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: I'm essentially given enough space for a cache (memPtr) and using a pointer would invalid the premise of a cache, because I'm allocating more space outside the cache.

Comment: If SECTOR_SIZE is 256, for example, I'd like Entry to be 4+256 big.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I'm reading the question correctly, you're asking how to get a contiguous block of memory that can be accessed with a (smaller) `Entry *`

The most common way is to define your structure like:

`typedef struct Entry {
    int counter;
    unsigned char block[1];
}`

Depending on the behavior of your compiler you can also define block to be a zero length array.

You can then malloc the space that you require for the structure and the SECTOR_SIZE:

`int AddEntry(void *data) {
   Entry *entry;
   entry = malloc(sizeof(Entry) + ((SECTOR_SIZE-1) * sizeof(unsigned char));
   // obligitory NULL checks assumed here`

// fill in structure
   entry->counter = 1;
   memcpy(entry->block, data, SECTOR_SIZE);
   memcpy(&memPtr[0], &entry, sizeof(Entry) + ((SECTOR_SIZE-1) * sizeof(unsigned char));
   return 0;
}

This will also allow you to access, say, the 78th byte of `block` by:
`entry->block[77]`

Comment: You could equally use a flexible array: `unsigned char block[]`

Comment: I guess there isn't then a way to create it on the stack?

Comment: @Andrew why is there a SECTOR_SIZE-1?

Comment: @Rio the "SECTOR_SIZE-1" is because the sizeof(Entry) already includes one byte for the array in the definition.